# Optimizing variable check in java

Tags: java

I have been working the codingbat exercises lately and here is my solution for one of the problem

```
public boolean makes10(int a, int b) {
  return (a == 10 || b == 10 || a+b == 10);
  }
```

The code itself works but i am wondering if this code can be optimised further since the 2 variable (a and b) both check if they equals to same value.I am referring to `a == 10 || b == 10`

Comment: No. This looks fine. If `a==10` is `true` , then the conditions following it would not be checked / evaluated

Comment: I agree with TheLostMind, the shortcircuits are enough optimisations. If you feel that `a+b==10` is more frequent, put it in the beggining.

Comment: @TheLostMind wouldn't it be better then to put `a+b == 10` first. So if the total ads to 10 it doesn't bother checking the others, rather then `a = 6` and `b = 4` and then finally getting to the last one?

Comment: @user3189142 - What if `a` is `6` and b is `10` ? :P

Comment: @Jyr but this as an answer

Comment: by using `|| `operator "short-circuit", you already optimize the condition. unless you are using `|` 'coz it will evaluate both sides

Comment: @assylias you are right ....@Jyr is there a way to make it compile...i really like the shorthand way

Comment: @user2650277 no there isn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the first condition in your if block is returned as true it doesnot moves to the next condition as `true || false = true` and `true || true = true` ie, if the first argument is true the second is left unevaluated, because the whole expression must then be true. So your present code is fine as far as the optimization is concerned. 
The behavior is called the [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

From the [docs](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ww1B9O_yVGsC&pg=PA390&lpg=PA390&dq=but%20evaluates%20its%20right-hand%20operand%20only%20if%20the%20value%20of%20its%20left%20java&source=bl&ots=Sf0L8mScpH&sig=Yx_nh-FVE6ZKBq4gboerChIxwWA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4l0vVZLyJcL4apyHgegE&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=but%20evaluates%20its%20right-hand%20operand%20only%20if%20the%20value%20of%20its%20left%20java&f=false):

> The || operator is like | (§15.22.2), but evaluates its right-hand
>   operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is false. [...] At
>   run time, the left-hand operand expression is evaluated first; [...]
>   if the resulting value is true, the value of the conditional-or
>   expression is true and the right-hand operand expression is not
>   evaluated. If the value of the left-hand operand is false, then the
>   right-hand expression is evaluated; [...] the resulting value becomes
>   the value of the conditional-or expression. Thus, || computes the same
>   result as | on boolean or Boolean operands. It differs only in that
>   the right-hand operand expression is evaluated conditionally rather
>   than always.